# I am trying to protect a page in reactJs, but getting this error

Tags: reactjs

ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amank\Desktop\auth mern\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure
a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

//HERE IS MY CODE

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [user,setUser] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!token) {
      navigate("/login");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const decoded = jwt.decode(token);`your text`
      if (!decoded) {
        throw new Error();
      }else{
        setUser(decoded.name)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcom: {user || "No user found"}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the 'stream' module cannot be found. This is likely due to changes in webpack that no longer include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.

Did you try doing what the error is suggesting (adding this to your webpack config) ?

```
resolve: {
  fallback: { 
    "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify")
  }
}
```

I suppose you could try to also alternatively install the 'stream-browserify' module and use it as a polyfill.

Comment: tried but not working